# Is is possible that 2 classifier give me the exact same results?

Tags: r, classification

I'm trying to classify an expression dataset composed by 23 control person and 15 patient, I'm using LDA and RF that actually give me the same result(Sensitivity = 1 Specificity = 0.95 and accuracy 0.94) (Lasso give me different results), is it possible and if why?

```
library(GEOquery)
library(pca3d)
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
library(ggbiplot)
library("genefilter")
library("randomForest")
library("GEOquery")
library(ggplot2)
gse<- getGEO("GSE5058", destdir = ".", getGPL = FALSE)

pData(gse[[1]])
##Check to my DataSet

tail(gse[[1]], 15)
pData(gse)

gse <- gse[[1]]
gse
pData(gse)
colnames(pData(gse))


##expression table
ex2 <- exprs(gse)
rownames(ex2)


##Normalization to median
channel.medians=apply(log(ex2),2,median)
normalized.log.x=sweep(log(ex2),2,channel.medians,"-")

boxplot(normalized.log.x)
normalized.log.x <- normalized.log.x+1
my_data <- log(normalized.log.x)
my_data <- na.omit(my_data)
dim(my_data)
boxplot(my_data)

## LDA Regression ### Using train and test set
ex2 <- my_data[,2:39]
ex2
dim(ex2)
f <- factor(c(rep("control",23),rep("affected",15)))
tt40 <- rowttests(ex2,f)

dim(tt40)
keepers <- which(p.adjust(tt40$p.value, method = "bonferroni")<0.01)
ex3 <- ex2[keepers,]
dim(ex3)
tex3 <- t(ex3)
library("caret")
library("e1071")
library("lattice")
### No cross ###
dat<-cbind(as.data.frame(tex3),f)
colnames(dat)[ncol(dat)] <- "AFFECTED"
dat$AFFECTED

### No cross ##S
##

    control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number=10)
    control
    metric <- "Accuracy"
    control
    fit_lda <- train(AFFECTED~.,data=dat, method="lda", metric=metric,trControl=control)
    summary(fit_lda)
      lda
    fit_rf <- train(AFFECTED~., data=dat, method="rf", metric=metric, trControl=control)
    fit_rf
    results <-resamples(list(LDA=fit_lda, RF=fit_rf))
    summary(results)
    print(fit_rf)
    print(fit_lda)
    ggplot(results) + labs(y = "Accuracy")  
    fit_rf
    confusionMatrix(fit_rf)
    confusionMatrix(fit_lda)
```

Comment: You would need to show more detail of your dataset and code to really say. Generally it is always possible for different algorithms to produce different results, especially with such as small trainings set.

Comment: I've added the code, you can easily download the dataset from GEO